MySQL JSON_OBJECTAGG - How to fix "PDOException: SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3158 JSON documents may not contain NULL member names" error?
I'm implementing a classic "Three-Table Tag System" using MySQL 8 and PHP:

the first Table ("Posts") contains posts (PostId, PostTitle, PostSummary, ...);
the second Table ("Tags") contains tags (TagId, TagName, TagSlug);
the third Table ("TagsMap") contains tags associated to each post (PostId, TagId).

The query I wrote to show the first 10 posts is:
SELECT p.PostTitle, p.PostSummary, ..., 
JSON_OBJECTAGG(t.TagSlug, t.TagName)
FROM (SELECT ... FROM Posts WHERE ... ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 10) p 
LEFT JOIN TagsMap tm ON p.PostId = tm.TagId 
LEFT JOIN Tags t ON tm.TagName = t.TagId
GROUP BY p.PostId
ORDER BY p.PostId DESC

It works.
The problem araises when a post has no associated tags. In this case, I get the following error:
"PDOException: SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3158 JSON documents may not contain NULL member names".

In other words, JSON_OBJECTAGG's key (t.TagSlug) cannot be null.
How can I fix it?
SQL Fiddle
Expected result using JSON_OBJECTAGG:
Title 3 | Summary 3 | NULL
Title 2 | Summary 2 | {"tag-slug-2": "tag name 2", "tag-slug-3": "tag name 3"}
Title 1 | Summary 1 | {"tag-slug-1": "tag name 1"}

Shouldn't p.PostId = tm.TagId be p.Postid = tm.PostId, and tm.TagName = t.TagId be tm.TagId = t.TagId? Please post the actual query, as well as sample input data.

The documentation says that it returns NULL if there are no matching rows. Do you have actual NULL values in the Tags table?

There are no NULL values in the "Tags" table.

For completeness: I don't get any error if I use GROUP_CONCAT(t.TagSlug), GROUP_CONCAT(t.TagName) instead of JSON_OBJECTAGG(t.TagSlug, t.TagName).

@Barmar The query is correct: I need to show, on the same page, a list of all the tags-names (e.g.: "bed and breakfast") and tags-slugs (e.g. "bed-and-breakfast") associated to that ten posts.

Your joining relationships seem all wrong. Why are you relating PostID to TagId instead of PostID?

Please post sample input and the desired result. Put them in the question, not comments. Use plain text, not screenshots, so we can copy and paste. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for how to post tables.

@Barmar Added SQL Fiddle to my question.

I still think ON p.PostId = tm.TagId should be ON p.PostId = tm.PostId. It makes no sense to use tm.TagId for both p.PostId and t.TagId

The query in the fiddle has ON tm.TagId = t.TagId, which is not the same as ON tm.TagName = t.TagId in the question.

Add the expected result to the question.

As an alternative, you can use a subquery to retrieve the tags:
SELECT PostId, PostTitle, PostSummary,
  (SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(t.TagSlug, t.TagName)
   FROM TagsMap tm
   JOIN Tags t ON tm.TagId = t.TagId
   WHERE tm.PostId = p.PostId
  ) TagsObject
FROM Posts p
ORDER BY PostId DESC LIMIT 10;

Output:
+--------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| PostId | PostTitle | PostSummary | TagsObject                                               |
+--------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|      3 | Title 3   | Summary 3   | NULL                                                     |
|      2 | Title 2   | Summary 2   | {"tag-name-2": "tag name 2"}                             |
|      1 | Title 1   | Summary 1   | {"tag-name-1": "tag name 1", "tag-name-2": "tag name 2"} |
+--------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

See fiddle

Which solution do you find better in terms of performance: this one or the CTE one?

@AbsoluteBeginner This one is probably a bit faster. It's more straightforward (no GROUP BY to compute).

I assume you want results for all the posts, whether they have tags or not. So you can't just use WHERE t.tagSlug IS NOT NULL, because that would leave out the posts that have no tags.
Run two queries, one for posts that have at least one tag, and one for posts that have no tags. Optionally union the results.
(SELECT p.PostId, p.PostTitle, p.PostSummary,
  JSON_OBJECTAGG(t.TagSlug, t.TagName) AS TagsObject
FROM (SELECT PostId, PostTitle, PostSummary FROM Posts) p
INNER JOIN TagsMap tm ON p.PostId = tm.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON tm.TagId = t.TagId
GROUP BY p.PostId)
UNION
(SELECT p.PostId, p.PostTitle, p.PostSummary,
   JSON_OBJECT()
FROM (SELECT PostId, PostTitle, PostSummary FROM Posts) p
LEFT OUTER JOIN TagsMap tm ON p.PostId = tm.PostId
WHERE tm.TagId IS NULL
GROUP BY p.PostId)
ORDER BY PostId DESC;

Tested on MySQL 8.0.37, here is the output given your example dbfiddle:
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
| PostId | PostTitle | PostSummary | TagsObject                   |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+
|      3 | Title 3   | Summary 3   | {}                           |
|      2 | Title 2   | Summary 2   | {"tag-name-2": "tag name 2"} |
|      1 | Title 1   | Summary 1   | {"tag-name-1": "tag name 1"} |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------+


You could also use JSON_OBJECT() to create an empty object in the second subquery, so all rows will have an object there.

@Barmar Good idea -- I've edited the example to show that.

@Bill Karwin Added SQL Fiddle to my question.

@AbsoluteBeginner I have tested with your example data and edited the query. I included the result I got.

There's a typo in my SQL Fiddle (sorry): "tag-name-2" should be "tag-slug-2", and "tag-name-1" should be "tag-slug-1". But your result is exactly what I need.

You can use UNION ALL here.

And why FROM (SELECT PostId, PostTitle, PostSummary FROM Posts) p instead of just FROM Posts p?

@Olivier There are other statements inside FROM (SELECT ... FROM Posts) p. See the query in my question.

@AbsoluteBeginner It's still unnecessary. If you want to add a filtering condition, use FROM Posts p INNER JOIN ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ....

@Olivier You're right. Thank you very much! There's a lot I have to learn about MySQL...

@AbsoluteBeginner However, to optimize the query, it does make sense to use FROM (SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY PostId DESC LIMIT 10) p (in both queries), otherwise MySQL will probably need to scan the whole Posts table.

@Olivier Isn't the second LIMIT 10 redundant?

@AbsoluteBeginner In fact I think the best way is to use a CTE (see fiddle). You can add a WHERE clause to the CTE to filter posts.

@Olivier You fiddle query doesn't show all 3 posts.

@AbsoluteBeginner That's because I put LIMIT 2 in the CTE.

@Olivier Look at this: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=75b32aa0-2ead-4fcf-b34a-a316463c2e8e - Post n. 3 is showed twice.

There was a mistake in a join condition; see this.

@Olivier. Thanks. I didn't know "Common Table Expressions". Do you think that - in my case - they can improve the query's performance?

@AbsoluteBeginner The query with the CTE is optimized: MySQL can execute the CTE by using the index on PostId and directly fetch the needed posts (without scanning the whole table).

An alternative approach is to add an IF statement (or CASE):
Note: please read the text below; this first example doesn't work.
IF(
  t.TagSlug IS NOT NULL, 
  JSON_OBJECTAGG(t.TagSlug, t.TagName), 
  JSON_OBJECT()
) AS tags

However, you'll notice MySQL is still evaluating the aggregation, even when it should return the second value, leading to the same error. I couldn't quite find out why but it's probably intentional.
Another approach would be to make the t.TagSlug key conditional:
JSON_OBJECTAGG(
  IF(t.TagSlug IS NOT NULL, t.TagSlug, "not-found"), 
  t.TagName
) AS tags

However, this would result in the following:



tags




{"not-found": null}


{"tag-name-2": "tag name 2"}


{"tag-name-2": "tag name 2"}



Combine these two approaches to get your desired output:
IF(
  t.TagSlug IS NOT NULL, 
  JSON_OBJECTAGG(COALESCE(t.TagSlug, ""), t.TagName), 
  JSON_OBJECT()
) AS tags

Note: COALESCE returns the first non-null value, so it's equivalent to the IF(t.TagSlug IS NOT NULL) used previously. The value can be an empty string, as it's discarded anyway.
Results in the following:



tags




{}


{"tag-name-2": "tag name 2"}


{"tag-name-2": "tag name 2"}




Maybe an alternative solution could be JSON_OBJECTAGG(IFNULL(t.TagSlug, ''), t.TagName), that returns {"": null}.
